# Using apply to modify different dataframe in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing

I'm running into some issues regarding the use of apply in Pandas.

I have a dataframe, where there is multiple measurements made on certain days, on different measurement sites. To give an example, Site 1 has 2 measurements to make, every 7 or so days. 
We know it has to be 2 measurements. So what I'm trying to do now is to check where on which days there were not enough measurements made.

```
   site  measurement  expected         date
0     1            2         1   01-01-2020
1     2            3         2   01-01-2020
2     3            4         2   01-01-2020
3     3            5         2   01-01-2020
4     2            1         2   08-01-2020
5     2            4         2   08-01-2020
```

I've made a sorted and aggregated DataFrame, that has aggregated the measurements, to basically be able to iterate over the measurements as to not go over the same days twice when there are multiple measurements.

```
   site  measurement  expected         date
0     1            2         1   01-01-2020
1     2            3         2   01-01-2020
2     3            9         2   01-01-2020
3     2            5         2   08-01-2020
```

For a function, I'm now using the function `filter_amount(df_sorted, df, group)`.

group is to count the amount of measurements made `df.groupby(["site_id", "date"]).count()`

```
   site  measurement         date
0     1            2   01-01-2020  
1     2            1   01-01-2020     
2     3            2   01-01-2020
3     2            2   08-01-2020
```

The current function basically goes like this:

```
def filter_amount(df_sorted, df, group):
    for i in df_sorted.index:
        "Locate amount of measurements for this day and site actually made, in group"

        Check how many measurements are expected.

        If not enough measurements:
            find all measurements in normal df and drop them
```

So in this example, the measurements from site 2 on 1-1-20 have to be dropped, because there are not enough measurements. The ones from 8-1-20 are valid, because they expect 2, and 2 happen.

The problem is that this is extremely slow with over 500k rows.

The variables I need, I get by using .at[], but I'm trying to make it faster by using apply so I can parallelize the operations, but can't figure it out. I'm doing the apply on df_sorted and passing the arguments needed in, but it's not actually dropping the measurements from the original df.

I have a feeling that it's possible to do it with some sort of groupby on the original df to save operations..

I hope it's clear enough, happy to elaborate any questions.

Comment: could you modify the example including the date column? so we can check and verify a possible solution

Comment: That should do it, although it shouldn't technically matter for the simplest approach. Thanks for your look at it

Comment: Could you explain better what is the criteria to discard measurements? Should all measurements from Site 2 be discarded for all dates?

Comment: Right, so if a day has too little measurements, all measurements from that day need to be discarded. The days where there's enough, are valid.